# Which version of Jboss eap Compatability with Java 8

Tags: jboss

My name Narasimha , Could you please tell me which version of Jboss eap compatible with Java8

Previosuly I tried with Jboss eap 7.2 but it didn't work.

My mailid 
vswamy448@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I have got jbosseap 6.4.0 working with JDK 1.8.
 If you are facing issues with java , try setting explicit java_home in standalone.conf and restart the jboss.

Comment: Thank you Adnan Khan , I will try